# Microsoft Teams - Why can't I record a meeting?

Tags: video, recording, microsoft-teams

I called my colleague on Microsoft Teams and my intention was to record the call (video + audio). However, there was no option for recording the meeting. Why is the recording option not appearing on Teams?

Comment: Please post your answer in the area below. You will be able to accept it as a self-answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible in Microsoft Teams *calls*.
It is only possible in Microsoft Teams **Meetings** and the Record Meeting option should be available there.

You have to schedule a meeting in the Teams Calendar and join it. You should invite other people to the meeting, if you want (you can join the meeting just by yourself, or just two people, then record the meeting).

Comment: if you have an nVidia GPU, you can just use ShadowPlay to record your call *or* meeting, assuming the audio it routed through your workstation.

Comment: @Arctiic Thanks! Unfortunately my machine has Intel graphics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 10, you can use Windows + G, and Record the Screen With Windows Games Hub.